# import xml file l to sql developer

Tags: sql, xml, database, oracle

Hello how i can import XML file to sql developer and show the data and make queries on sql developer with XML Data. Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you mean import an XML file into the database? SQL Developer is a desktop application for working with Oracle databases.

Comment: By default, SQL Developer wont parse/import XML into a table. But it will do CSV so perhaps use something like https://codebeautify.org/xml-to-csv-converter or similar to map your XML into a CSV and then import that

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear. 
You could use XMLTABLE and pass your data converting it into and XMLTYPE.

```
SELECT *
   FROM
   XMLTABLE('/OuterNode'
      PASSING XMLTYPE ('<OuterNode>
                                   <InnerNode1>123</InnerNode1> 
                                   <InnerNode2>456</InnerNode2>
                       </OuterNode>')
      COLUMNS 
         "InnerNode1" varchar2(6) PATH '/OuterNode/InnerNode1',
         "InnerNode2" varchar2(6) PATH '/OuterNode/InnerNode2'
         ) ;
```